# Why is my transfer fee not working in solidity

Tags: solidity, remix

The 3% transfer fee is not being taken out, do I have to add something to the transfer emit line to make it work? Also, will this transfer function cover buys and sells or just sells?

```
    function transfer(address to, uint256 value) external returns (bool) {
    uint256 fee = (value / 100) * 3; // Calculate 3% fee
        require(balanceOf(msg.sender) >= value, 'balance too low');
        balances[msg.sender] -= value;
        balances[admin] += fee;
        balances[to] += value - fee;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, value);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, value); // original code
```

This line emits the event saying "`to` received `value`", which is incorrect. In reality, `to` receives `value - fee`.

```
emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, value - fee); // corrected code
```